# Sequel migration. What should an IP address be in my migration file?

Tags: ruby, database, postgresql, sequel

So this is my sequel migration table. I am creating some dummy web software for the sake of learning and I am trying to create a database table called payloads that is taking in and organizing data that comes in via a cURL request. The cURL is coming in with data called payloads and I am trying to organize all of this data in my migration.

Here is my migration code:

```
Sequel.migration do
  change do
    create_table(:payloads) do
      primary_key   :id
      String        :url
      String        :requestedAt
      String        :respondedIn
      String        :referredBy
      String        :requestType
      String        :parameters
      String        :eventName
      String        :userAgent
      Integer       :resolutionWidth
      Integer       :resolutionHeight
      Integer       :ip
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my cURL request:

```
curl -i -d 'payload={"url":"http://jumpstartlab.com/blog","requestedAt":"2013-02-16 21:38:28 -0700","respondedIn":37,"referredBy":"http://jumpstartlab.com","requestType":"GET","parameters":[],"eventName": "socialLogin","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh%3B Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17","resolutionWidth":"1920","resolutionHeight":"1280","ip":"63.29.38.211"}' http://localhost:9393/sources/jumpstartlab/data
```

The curl request hits a post route (the curl request has -d which apparently means it needs to hit a post route) which has a create method. Here is that method.

```
  def self.create(attributes)
      #might need to turn symbols into strings
      binding.pry
      table.insert(
      :url => attributes[:url],
      :requestedAt => attributes[:requestedAt],
      :respondedIn => attributes[:respondedIn],
      :referredBy => attributes[:referredBy],
      :requestType => attributes[:requestType],
      :parameters => attributes[:parameters],
      :eventName => attributes[:eventName],
      :userAgent => attributes[:userAgent],
      :resolutionWidth => attributes[:resolutionWidth],
      :resolutionHeight => attributes[:resolutionHeight],
      :ip => attributes[:ip]
      )
    end
```

In the above code snippet, table is a method which is this:

```
def self.table
   DB.from(:payloads)
end
```

Here is my error message:

```
Sequel::DatabaseError - PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "63.29.38.211"
LINE 1: ...hrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17', '1920', '1280', '63.29.38....
                                                            ^
```

Any ideas what is going on? My thoughts are that my migration table isn't properly handling the IP field that is coming in via the payload. The payload is coming in and the params hash is probably converting everything to strings. When the data hits my migration table, I am attempting to convert some of those fields into Integers, but my migration table cannot convert an ip address string into an Integer. So what should my migration table field be for the IP column? Should it be Float? I could use string, but what if I don't want it to be read as a string?

Comment: What about INET? That would be the preferred datatype in PostgreSQL for a ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [pg_inet extension](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/pg_inet_rb.html).

> The pg_inet extension adds support for Sequel to handle PostgreSQL's
>   inet and cidr types using ruby's IPAddr class.